# Run job/script/any in backgorund with laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, queue

Using Laravel 5.3 and php7, I'm trying to run a script in the background. 
[Laravel Queues section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues#generating-job-classes) make it looks simple, but it's not working here.

Some code, here is my JOB, the one that I need to make work in background:

```
class EncodeBitmovin implements ShouldQueue{

    use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct(){}

    public function handle(){
        $cont = 0;
        while($cont < 3){
            ++$cont;
            sleep(1);
            (new Bitmovin())->testeeeee($cont);
        }
    }
}
```

And here my controller method, called from the view with AJAX:

```
public function callMe(Request $request) {

    // Do some stuff

    $job = (new EncodeBitmovin());
    dispatch($job);

    echo json_encode(array('code' => 1, 'info_from_some_stuff' => 'some_id'));
    return;
}
```

In this senary all works, BUT the "dispatch($job)" holds the echo with the response for the view, first the job runs completely, and only then the echo sends the response.

What I need is kind of an asynchronous call, where the "dispatch($job);" is called and the 'echo' is called right away, while the JOB still running independently.

Is that possible to be done? Is Queues the way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, queues will work for this. However, by default, Laravel starts off with the queue driver set to `sync`. If you look at your `.env` file, you should see `QUEUE_DRIVER=sync`.

When the queue driver is `sync`, all queued jobs are actually run synchronously, which is why your `echo` statement is not being run until the job is finished.

If you update your queue driver (in your `.env` file) to one of the actual queues ("database", "beanstalkd", "sqs", "redis", or "null"), then your queued job will be processed asynchronously, and your `echo` will run immediately after the job is dispatched.

Note, however, that you should actually have one of these queues setup before actually changing the driver. Also, once a real queue is setup and in use, you will need to start a queue worker if you want your jobs to actually be processed.